# PLSQL select substr between Nth and Mth occurance of character

Tags: regex, plsql, substring

I'm sure there is a simple function for exactly this problem, but I can't seem to find it...

I have a string containing multiple slashes, for example an URL. Let's say I want to obtain the substring between the second and fourth occurance of the slash, if exists, else I want everything following the second slash or simply "" if it contains less than 2 slashes.

Hence: `'ab/cd/ef/gh/ij'` should be selected as `'ef/gh'` and `'abc/d'` should be selected as `''`.

What is the magical function/combination of functions I'm looking for? Tried to play around with substr and regexp_substr, but it got messy quite rapidly, without the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I wasn't searching hard enough. The function `instr` does the trick, hence in combination with `substr`:

```
SUBSTR(string, INSTR(string,'/',1,2) + 1, INSTR(string,'/',1,4) - INSTR(string,'/',1,2)-1)
```

Still looks kind of dirty to me though, creativity is more than welcome.

Comment: This is pretty much the way I would usually do it. Encapsulate it in a function so that the rest of your code looks clean :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  I suspect the regex's could be simpler but it meets your requirements.  Note that the order in which you make the tests against the string in the case statement are very important, lest the str fall into the wrong test.

```
with tbl(rownbr, str) as (
  select 1, 'ab/cd/ef/gh/ij/x/x/x' from dual union
  select 2, 'aa/bb/cc'             from dual union
  select 3, 'gg/hh/ii/jj'          from dual union
  select 4, 'abc/d'                from dual union
  select 5, 'zz'                   from dual
)
select rownbr, 
       case 
         when regexp_count(str, '/') > 4 then
           regexp_replace(str, '^.*?/.*?/(.*?/.*?)/.*$', '\1')
         when regexp_count(str, '/') < 2 then
           NULL    
         when regexp_count(str, '/') < 4 then
           regexp_replace(str, '^.*?/.*?/(.*)$', '\1')
       end  result
from tbl;
```